# Cycles rendering issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, distort

While rendering in eevee, the render comes out alright but in cycles the mesh gets distorted. Can you please tell what could be possibly wrong?

[image]
This is in cycles

[image]
This is in eevee.
This is how I want the mesh to be like in cycles.
But I'm not sure what is causing the distortion.

Comment: We can only guess. Are there any displacement modifiers or shaders, or subdiv on the object? Please show us some settings, if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your material you've probably plugged a *Displacement* node into the *Output*, you can cut it off or, if you want to keep a displacement effect, go into the *Material panel > Settings > Displacement*, choose *Bump Only*:

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot :)